# Setting an array of bits

Tags: c++, arrays, mask, bit

I'm writing a program for my OO class and I'm having some trouble with my cout statements. The program is supposed to take in a value and convert it to a bitwise array. My problem is that no matter what number I put in it couts every element in the array to 0. The assignment said to initialize every element to 0 in the constructor, but when comparing it to the & operator in the Query function it can only return false. Any suggestions? (Note: we can't use vectors or any of the premade functions.)

in header file:

```
private:
    static const CSIZE = 8 * sizeof(char);
    int arraySize;
    unsigned char* barray;
```

in .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bitarray.h"
using namespace std;

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const BitArray& a)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.arraySize * a.CSIZE; i++)
        os << a.Query(i);

    return os;
}

BitArray::BitArray(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n % CSIZE != 0)
        arraySize = (n / CSIZE) + 1;
    else
        arraySize = n / CSIZE;

    barray = new unsigned char[arraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        barray[i] = 0;
}

unsigned char BitArray::Mask (unsigned int num) const
{
    return (1 << num % CSIZE);
}

void BitArray::Set   (unsigned int index)
{
    unsigned int i = index / CSIZE;
    barray[i] |= Mask (index);
}

bool BitArray::Query (unsigned int index) const 
{
    unsigned int i = index / CSIZE;

    if (barray[i] & Mask (index))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Main program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "sieve.h"
#include "bitarray.h"

int main()
{
   unsigned int i, max, counter = 0;

   cout << "\nEnter a positive integer for the maximum value: ";
   cin >> max;

   BitArray ba(max);

   Sieve(ba);                    // find the primes (marking the bits)

   cout << "The bit array looks like this: \n"
        << ba
        << '\n';  

   cout << "\nPrimes less than " << max << ':' << '\n';
   for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
   {    
       if (ba.Query(i))
       {
        counter++;
            cout << i;
            if (counter % 8 == 0)
            {
                cout << '\n';
                counter = 0;
            }
            else
                cout << '\t';
       }
   }


   cout << "\nGoodbye!\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mention that your problem involves `cout`, but your sample code doesn't show it - can you please include the actual code you're using?

Comment: `static const CSIZE = 8 * sizeof(char) * arraySize;` How is this supposed to work?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, the cout is only in the main program. I attached a link to the main program we were given. For the .cpp file we were asked to do an overload of the ostream. EDIT: OH! I didn't realize it was chopped off in the code, sorry! Still kinda new at this...

Comment: @MooseBoys, I was editing this as I was updating my code and fixed the wrong thing! Thanks, that was for my ostream operator. I'll edit that.

Comment: You did not show the code for the `Sieve()` function that is manipulating the array bits before you output them.

Comment: Remy, I put it back in, and I see what you mean. I think that might be it. I thought Sieve was only for finding the primes and essentially a "part b" of this program. I'll go work on Sieve then! Thank you! :)

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1.